# Gnome is not prompting for a password

Tags: gnome, password

I’m using using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Sony Vaio. My problem is that the gnome shell is not prompting me for a password when the PC is already turned on. When I restart, it is prompting me for one.

I’ve tried `sudo service lightdm restart` but that didn't work. When I did that my screen turned itself off and I couldn't do anything so I had to force shut down and after that it showed an "Ubuntu has a bug please send error report", so I did send an error report.

*How can I have a prompt for a password again?*

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
# seahorse
```

Then choose gnome click on Lock pad icon and set a password for it or enable.

Comment: when i click on gnome it showed password keyring, PGP key ,private key, secure shell key, stored password. out of those which one i've to enable.